# How does the stackexchange licencing work when you are the author of the questions?

Tags: support, licensing, attribution

My coding is getting to the stage I am starting to think about publishing with a GPL licence when I use version control like github. I thought of the GPL licence because it is free and therefore seems like the best and most fair way to develop an idea. However, I am getting to wonder how licensing applies to various situations I personally find myself in as a person who is learning code with languages like java and typset with latex.

After browsing through some topics on the issue of licensing I spotted a [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) giving information about the rules here but I am not certain how to interpret them in situations like remixing a latex code with help from stack exchange and then publishing it again under the GPL. Is it not allowed, even if you specifically attributed the part which you got help with on SE?

I am also curious to learn how attribution actually gets interpreted in cases where asking a question on the SE really didn't contribute directly but gave a bit of help on a part you got stuck with or didn't know how to do and may not have even used in the end but it taught you how to do what you wanted to do: Are you giving away the 'ownership' of your work by getting help with any part of it on here?

Apologies if these questions have already been covered but I searching GPL licensing topics on here did not bring much up.